# Magento Checkout Page content (not in CMS)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Can someone please explain the Magento directory structure in relation to URL?  I'm using the community version I believe.

So I had someone ask me to update some content on a magento checkout page.  I'm not familiar with the framework that much so trying to figure out the file/folder structure has been a challenge for me. That said, the checkout is located on http://domain.com/magento/checkout/onepage/

The only thing I'm trying to update is some "terms" that are showing up in the checkout tab, which I can't seem to find through the Magento CMS anywhere (pages, terms, etc), and the other thing I'm trying to add is the coupon code field display, which I checked (at least what I think) were the corresponding XML and PHTML files and the code isn't commented out for the coupon code, so I suspect my problem is with the fact that I'm just not looking in the right project folder/file, or there's some kind of inheritance from default that I'm missing.

Comment: You believe you're using the community version? Can you specify this?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.7.0.2 - I see this version at the bottom of the cms dashboard.  When downloading I only see this version in "Community", but again, I didn't set this up and am completely new to this framework....

Comment: Those Terms are editable in Sales -> Terms and Conditions (I think, on mobile). They can be set to display in the checkout or not.

Comment: I thought so too, however these terms were actually hardcoded within one of the phtml files, which is why I had such a hard time finding them.... the debug hint below actually helped me identify the files I needed.  Didn't realize how many files were part of this framework!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 to debug this is to enable template path hints from the admin HTML console. This will show you what template files are being loaded. From there you should be able to resolve your problem.

```
System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Advanced -> Template hints
```

However I've looked at my local install of CE and on the one page checkout don't see any reference to terms. Perhaps this is an extra block being inserted?

Comment: Thanks for the response... I see a "debug -> profiler" which displayed a few details at the bottom, and under "Template Settings" I have "Allow Symlinks", but I don't see anything resembling "Template Hints", which would be GREAT by the sounds of it!!

Comment: Take it back... had to toggle to "Main Website" configuration scope to see the options.... will see where that gets me!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

*Applies to all versions of Magento*

## Magento path hints

If you enable **Template Path Hints** on a site and refresh the cache, **ALL** site visitors will see the hints.

To avoid this, put you external ip address into:

`System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Developer Client Restrictions -> Allowed IPs (comma separated)`

Example: goto http://www.whatismyip.com/ and note down your ip address (for example   103.167.139.74). Enter the ip into the field and save.

Doing this will only show the path hints to visitors from the above mentioned ip address.

### Path to template files

This will depend on the theme used. Let's pretend you're using the default magento theme on community edition. Then you will find all of the templates at `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/`

Checkout parts live in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage`

Answer (score 0):

Magento Path hints for sure or if you can invest a few bucks buy commerce Bug 2. Now if this is your first time working with magento I strongly advice you to backup your database, copy all the files from your theme and set a development enviroment. Other thing you should do is to disable the cache and tell magento to display erros while workin (check your index.php `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`}